# Limescale removal in bathroom (not tiled)

Tags: bathroom, shower, cleaning

I have a limescale problem in my bathroom. As you can see, it follows the arc of the shower door and it's also pretty bad inside the shower.

[image]

I have tried various limescale removal products but most of these require the surface to be rinsed off after use. I used the product and rinsed it off inside the shower cubicle and mopped the floor a few times outside the shower cubicle but this didn't work as the picture shows.

How can I remove it? I should also add that the floor is not made of smooth tiles like the wall is.

Comment: What is the floor made of?
Typically removing lime scale is done by chemically dissolving it with an acid.  The first step is to figure out if the flooring will be affected by acid, and if not use a stronger acid.

Comment: @DaveM no idea since it's student accommodation.

Comment: "not tiled" ?? Except for the door  it is all tile.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I meant smooth tiles. I don't know what it's made of but it's slightly rougher than the wall tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a product with an acid that dissolves minerals found in hard water. Cleaners with *phosphoric acid* and newer products supposedly more environmentally sensitive with *formic acid* work nicely.

I think all of them will recommend rinsing, if for no other reason than to flush away the dissolved limescale.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CLR Calcium Lime Rust remover?  I have never found this not to work on any of the 3 I have used it on multiple properties I have no connection to that product except as a satisfied customer. It needs to be wiped up after application on the floor.

Comment: Do you mean this product? https://www.amazon.co.uk/CLR-Calcium-Remover-Enhanced-Formula/dp/B00009EFEX 

It says it must be rinsed thoroughly. Are you sure it can just be wiped off?

Comment: Yes I have used it and mentioned that it needs to be wiped up after use on the floor in my answer.

Comment: Thanks - I was reading the instructions on the back of the product which said rinse thoroughly with cold water but I guess if wiping is sufficient, that'll do it for me